# Android - Unable to pass Spinner value to jsonSendRequest

Tags: java, android, spinner

I'm new to Android development and Java in general, so I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

I'm writing a currency convertor app and using Volley requests to send a request to an API to retrieve conversion rates.

Right now I am hardcoding the countries into the URL, which works as the conversion rate is successfully retrieved and displayed. I have two Spinners right now and the goal is to retrieve the string value of the selected Spinner value and then use those values for the json request.

I've created two setOnItemSelectedListeners for both Spinners and set the variable containing the value of the string to that. However, I'm getting an null object reference.

Here is what I have:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RequestQueue rq;
    Double conversionDouble;

    Spinner toSpinner, fromSpinner;
    Spinner toSpinnerText, fromSpinnerText;
    private Button convertBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addItemsOnToSpinner();
        addListenerOnButton();
        jsonSendRequest();

        Button convertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convertBtn);
        final EditText fromAmountEditText = findViewById(R.id.fromAmountEditText);

        convertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView toAmountTextView = findViewById(R.id.toAmountTextView);
                DecimalFormat percentageFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
                Double fromAmount = Double.parseDouble(fromAmountEditText.getText().toString());
                String result = "$" + percentageFormat.format(conversionDouble*fromAmount);
                toAmountTextView.setText(result);
            }
        });
        rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    }

    public void jsonSendRequest() {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        // String url = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=CAD_USD&compact=ultra";
        String url = "http://free.currencyconverterapi.com/api/v3/convert?q=" + fromSpinnerText + "_" + toSpinnerText  + "&compact=ultra";

        // Request a string response
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        JSONObject jsonobject = null;
                        try {
                            jsonobject = new JSONObject(response);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (jsonobject.has(fromSpinnerText + "_" + toSpinnerText)) {
                            try {
                                conversionDouble = jsonobject.getDouble(fromSpinnerText + "_" + toSpinnerText);
                                // conversionDouble = jsonobject.getDouble(fromSpinnerText + "_" + toSpinnerText);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    public void addItemsOnToSpinner(){

        Spinner toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);
        Spinner fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);

        List<String> currency = new ArrayList<String>();
        currency.add("USD");
        currency.add("CAD");
        currency.add("CNY");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
         this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currency
        );

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        toSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        fromSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        fromSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String fromSpinnerText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        toSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String toSpinnerText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        Spinner fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fromSpinner);
        Spinner toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.toSpinner);
        Button convertBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convertBtn);

    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared a few class variables related to your `Spinner`:

```
Spinner toSpinner, fromSpinner;
Spinner toSpinnerText, fromSpinnerText;
```

You have also correctly defined the `onItemSelected()` method for the `setOnItemSelectedListener`.

But, I assume you meant to make the class variables `Spinner toSpinnerText, fromSpinnerText;` to actually be:

```
String toSpinnerText = "";
String fromSpinnerText= "";
```

So that you could call:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     fromSpinnerText = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
}
```

Notice that the variable `fromSpinnerText` in the method is now using the class variable instead of the local variable you defined inside the `onItemSelected()` method.

The same goes for the `onItemSelected()` method for the other `Spinner` and `toSpinnerText`.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed that. I'm now having an issue where the *SpinnerText class variables aren't being set to the chosen spinner value. I was debugging it for a while and it seems like when the JsonSendRequest function is called, the *SpinnerText class variables are still initialized to empty strings. I find this odd (should I?) this occurs because of the order of the functions I am calling with.

Comment: @RubiksH :: I'm sorry I  have not had time to get to the question you posed in the comment above! I realize this is an important step in getting your code working properly. Right now I am working on something, but would like to help. I suggest you post a new question (with the revised code) explaining the new issue. I will look for that post a bit later...but as quick as the SO community is with answering questions I am certain it will be answered quickly. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. I have posted the new question.